# Including my own shared library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following code in my CMakeLists.txt for finding my shared library `libsieve.so`

```
set(CPPLIB_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../core/build")
find_library(CPPLIB_SIEVE_LIBRARY NAMES libsieve PATHS CPPLIB_DIR)
```

But it fails and won't find my library. I have the following directory structure:

- core

  - build: `libsieve.so`
- project: `CMakeLists.txt`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why cmake doesn't find the needed library but I can suggest a way to make it happen with the help cmake-gui: if the first run of "configure" fails to find the library you can point it to the needed library manually (set the full absolute path). Most of the time such solution works for me.

Also if the library was built with one tool chain (say, Intel C++) and you project is being built with another tool chain (say, clang) the failure to find the library may be due to binary incompatibility between the project and the library.

Upd. The original problem was referencing CPPLIB_DIR. It should have been:

```
find_library(CPPLIB_SIEVE_LIBRARY NAMES sieve PATHS ${CPPLIB_DIR})
```

Comment: I'm building the `libsieve.so` library myself with another cmake file. Could this be the problem? it looks like this: `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release") add_library(sieve SHARED Sieve.cpp)`

Comment: Does the library exist as libsieve.so compiled object at the time when you use CMake for your project? If not, it obviously is the reason of the problem because CMake doesn't actually compile your code, it just creates makefiles. find_library looks for already compiled objects, is't nothing strange that it doesn't find it if it doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: Another guess: try to write it like this:
find_library(CPPLIB_SIEVE_LIBRARY NAMES libsieve PATHS ${CPPLIB_DIR})

Comment: Cool thank you Dmitry, that was in fact the problem (and I had to reference to my library with `sieve` instead of `libsieve`)

Answer (score 0):

Cmake `find_library` expect you to provide the library name or the library file name.

You mixed the two by adding a "lib" prefix to your library name. So you should try to replace `libsieve` by either `sieve` or `libsieve.so`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that but it didn't work. I even used absolute paths but still no library found.